# Upload and Play mp4 videos on twiki

Tags: video, upload, mp4, playback, twiki

How to upload and play mp4 files on twiki site?

Best Ragards,
Srinivas.M

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TWiki, but [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org) (a fork of TWiki) has the [ObjectPlugin](http://foswiki.org/Extensions/MediaPlugin) which allows you upload and play a number of media types. It doesn't mention `mp4` specifically, but may work.

You may be able to port the plugin to TWiki, or upgrade your wiki to Foswiki.